# how to configure maven-release-plugin to copy assets as part of build cycle?

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-release-plugin

I have the following requirement.

As part of our release cycle (when artifacts are pushed to artifactory), we need some assets from project directory to be copied to different machine inside a new folder.

Example:

project/root/src/main/assets/*

copied to

v4 (create this directory before scp the files).

we currently use `maven-release-plugin` for release and  wondering if it is possible to configure `maven-release-plugin` to do so. I tried searching for it but in vain.

Any help here is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You should separate release step and deployments...copying such assets is a kind of deployment which should be separated from building a release...